# Is there a way to add a TAG to a NetworkImageView with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

It is very easy to add a TAG to a request with Volley, but when it comes to a `NetworkImageView`, I don't see a way to specify a TAG to the request that is handled and added to the queue by the `ImageLoader`.

A request TAG would help me to easily identify the request and react consequently.

Therefore, how can I add a TAG to a request made by a `NetworkImageView` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way unless you override ImageLoader and NetworkImageView.

The 'guy' who is creating the request is

> ImageLoader.makeImageRequest

so you need to pass the tag to it.

However you can use [jus](https://github.com/apptik/jus) which is based on volley and support this feature.

you currently need to use the SNAPSHOT version:

```
compile 'io.apptik.comm:jus-android:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

and you can set the tag using the "requestTag" argument in the xml layout:

```
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".fragments.JusFragment">
....
        <io.apptik.comm.jus.ui.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/networkImageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            app:requestTag="ImageTag1"
            />
```

....

OR

from the code before you call setImageUrl():

```
    networkImageView.setRequestTag("ImageTag2");
    networkImageView.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```